# How to control 2 similar monitors from Samsung with Logitech Harmony?

Tags: display, tv, remote-control

### My Problem

Yesterday I set up a new *Samsung T24A350* for my PC. The monitor has a build-in TV receiver and a remote control.

Unfortunately I also have a Samsung TV and whenever I use the monitors remote or my Logitech Harmony *both the TV and the monitor turn on*, switch channels, chang volume and so.

### My Question

Is there a way to change the IR codes of the remote control or disable the remote for the monitor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A low tech solution for your problem:

Cover the IR receiver on the monitor with black electrical tape.

Alternatively, put tape on the remote IR transmitter and cut out a very small strip. This way it will work with whichever device you point it towards. (never tried this IRL)

Comment: Already done that, not with tape, but the receiver is covered. ;-)